# How do I send url params from flutter

Tags: node.js, mongodb, http, flutter, get

I want to get a data set of Posts collection using postId. I created a route in my api for it. It works in postman. But I want that same thing in my flutter app. 
I want to **send PostId with my Http GET request in flutter** .

my code is

```
class _PostScreenState extends State<PostScreen> {
    List data;

  Future<List> getData() async {
    final response = await http.get("http://192.168.1.100:3000/posts?postId: 5e6619d9099432c2dc68c1b9");
    return json.decode(response.body);
  }

  @override
  void initState() { 
    super.initState();
     this.getData();
  }
```

and in my api route

```
    router.get('/:postId', (req, res, next) => {
    res.status(200).json({
        message: 'Post get /posts',
        postId: req.params.postId
    });
});
```

I want to send postId in my get request and get data from response.

```
 final response = await http.get("http://192.168.1.100:3000/posts?postId: 5e6619d9099432c2dc68c1b9");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `?` for only query params, and for URL params you should write like this,

```
 final response = await http.get("http://192.168.1.100:3000/posts/5e6619d9099432c2dc68c1b9");
```

and no need to mention *postId* in URL.

And while returning the response you have to create a Map out of it so that you can access the result.

```
return new Map<String, dynamic>.from(response.data);
```

Comment: it comes that error bro.  Exception has occurred.
_TypeError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<List<dynamic>>') from in  return json.decode(response.body); line